# I am not able to detect any sound

Tags: sound

quite new to linux. 
I am not able to detect any sound 
How can I check if the sound card is functional? 
How do I down load the drivers?

Comment: Hello Ravji. Can you execute this command in Terminal/other CLI: `cat /proc/version` and add the output to your question? Also please add the output of `cat /proc/asound/car*/co* |  grep Codec` and `cat /proc/asound/cards`

Comment: ... In the meantime, if you're impatient to get things going, I would suggest going through the basic (Sound Troubleshooting)[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure] steps of the Ubuntu Help Wiki, and if those do not solve your problem, add some of the useful information you find out using those steps to your question, including error messages.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked if something is wrong in the ´sound´ tab in the systems settings menu? (the icon with a crossed wrench and screwdriver)
you can check if Ubuntu has listed your soundcard, or something has not been configurated correctly.
if not, it probably hasn't recognized the soundcard yet.

second thing that probably can help is to check the ´software and updates´ program.
the tab ´drivers´ maybe show possible alternitive drivers for the soundcard on your computer, to make it work.

i hope this is info will be helpful to you